# Objective-c calling method without []

Tags: objective-c

Whats the difference between the method calls:

`time.text = s;

[time setText:s];`

if any?

The tutorial from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/JumpRightIn/iPhone101/Articles/06_ImplementingController.html uses both:

`- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

    self.userName = self.textField.text;

    NSString *nameString = self.userName;

    if ([nameString length] == 0) {

        nameString = @"World";

    }

    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];

    self.label.text = greeting;

}`

When to use what?
Im relative new to Objective-C if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers have some merit, but also have some things confused.  Here's my take:

The bracket notation is the general syntax for sending messages / invoking methods.

There are all sorts of different methods. One particular kind of methods are accessors – setters and getters for properties.

The dot syntax is an alternative form for invoking accessors. It's a somewhat newer style, just added to the language in the last several years. Using it is purely optional, if you find it clearer and less verbose. The difference is purely cosmetic. Using dot syntax is identical to invoking an accessor, either a getter or setter depending on how the subexpression is used within the larger expression.

Comment: Very well explained... had English been my mother tongue, I would have written the same.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK They both are same...

```
time.text = s;
```

internally performs... `[time setText:s];`

The earlier is just the dot notation which some people find more easier to use and is quite prevalent in other languages.

EDIT:

One more thing to add is I am only referring to properties here, since only they have getters and setters. Method calling is a different thing as there you can pass more parameters.

Comment: This is untrue. Dot syntax is only available for properties, not all methods.

Comment: OP is asking about method calling as well as properties. And method calling differs from properties beyond the number of possible parameters.

Comment: isn't calling getters and setters a sub part of method calling..?

Comment: That's clearly not the OP's intent; he's asking about the difference between dot syntax and brackets, not the relative semantics of the phrase "method calling" when using properties.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are saying. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The dot syntax (`time.text = s`) is a special case used by property setters and getters. If you declare a property using the `@property` keyword and then `@synthesize` the setter and getter or declare the setter and getter to be generated independently using `@dynamic`, you can access the setter and getter using dot syntax.

As an example, in my interface file I declare a property myInt:

```
@property (readwrite, assign) int myInt;
```

In that statement `readwrite` means I want a getter and a setter and `assign` means I want the value to be assigned to `myInt` instead of retained or copied. Then in my interface I write:

```
@synthesize myInt;
```

I now have a property called `myInt` that I can access using `self.myInt` and set using `self.myInt = ...`.

Using square brackets like `[nameString length]` is the standard way to call a method on an object in Objective-C, and works for generated properties as well (`[self myInt]`). The dot-syntax is just a shortcut for properties only.

Comment: Dot syntax does not require declared properties. It is purely syntactic sugar for calling setters and getters. The only interaction with declared properties is that declared properties can specify alternate names for the setters and getters and dot syntax will respect that. For conventional properties, it deduces the accessor names.

Comment: Oh, so it just requires a `synthesize` or `dynamic`?

Comment: It doesn't require anything to do with `@property`, `@synthesize`, or `@dynamic`. It just requires that the appropriate accessor has been declared. `@property` is one way of declaring accessors, but you can also just declare them the old fashioned way, like `- (NSString*) text;` and (if the property is mutable) `- (void) setText:(NSString*)newText;`.  (`@synthesize` and `@dynamic` are not relevant to interface, only implementation, and so don't matter at all for dot syntax.)

Comment: Wow, I never knew that. That's awesome.